# Get the value of Dynamic Textboxes from Modal PopUp Extender

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, textbox, modalpopupextender

I have a Modal Popup Extender(MPE) , it has textboxes that are build dynamically depends on the number of input of the user, for example the user input "6" then 6 textboxes will be generated in MPE , Now my problem is, how am i going to get value of those textboxes and put it into the gridview??

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the value of each textbox you generate in an array or list of string, and then put it in ViewState then access them from code.